# Those students want to become a teacher/teachers. - are both of them acceptable?

Tags: plural-forms, singular

**Example 1**

> Those students want to become a teacher.

**Example 2**

> Those students want to become teachers.

Are both correct? Do they mean the same?

Example 1 may sound a little bit unnatural but I have read sentences like "If your students want to be a teacher, they need to take classes in the teacher preparation program."

So sometimes I wonder why.

Comment: "Those students want to become a teacher" is not idiomatic. It sounds more than "a bit" unnatural. Maybe if you had divided your class into groups: These students want to become a teacher; these students want to become an astronaut; these students want to become a detective.  In that case, the phrase "want to become a X" is like a label placed on the group.

Answer (score 2):

Your first one sounds somewhat off, as though those students hoped through joint effort to merge into a single newly formed teacher.

Your second example is fine.